# Session destroy in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Code igniter for my application. I have three controllers and three models  in may application homepage,dashboard and settings.I have started the session in homepage model and wanted destroy it in dashboard controller. here is my code

```
foreach($query->result(as $row) {
   $info = array(
       'loginid'    => $row->loginid,
       'firstname'  => $row->firstname,
       'emailid'    => $row->emailid,
       'logged_in'  => TRUE
   );
}

$this->session->set_userdata($info);
```

but my session array is not getting displyed in dashboard controller.

How I should destroy the session?

Comment: There are several syntax errors in the code above I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> $this->session->sess_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

You destroy the session with:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

as per [the codeigniter session documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

That said, I'm not sure how it's related to the code you posted and I'm pretty sure it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

> foreach($query->result(as $row)  Wrong

Please  use

```
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    $info = array( 
                'loginid'  => $row->loginid ,
                'emailid' => row->emailid,
           );
}
```

To display in dashboard controller. Try this

> $this->session->set_userdata($info);

Then you can destroy session by

> $this->session->sess_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->set_userdata([
                    'logged_in'  => TRUE
                    'loginid'    => $row->loginid,
                    'firstname'  => $row->firstname,
                    'emailid'    => $row->emailid,       
                ]);
```

And in your conntroller to unset like this

```
$this->session->set_userdata([
            'logged_in' => false,
            'loginid' => null
        ]);
```